# How to manage objects efficiently between components in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am a new bee to Angular and learning a lot from this forum. I have a scenario as below
Component 1 - ObjectA created and passed on to Component 2 on Form Submit
Component 2 - Makes changes to ObjectA and Sends back to Component1 (I am using ngOnChange event to listen to the change in the object)
HTML is updated in Component based on the changes

Few Code snippets
Component 1

```
Object1: Array<SomeInterface>;
@Input() Obj: Object;
@Output() Search: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

OnSubmit() {
  this.Submit.emit(this.Obj);
 }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.Object1 = this.Obj
}
```

Component 2

```
@Input() Obj: Array<SomeInterface> = [];

Submit(valueEmitted: Payload) {
// Changes made to object

}
```

I am working on Angular 13

[image]

Comment: So ... Any issue ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure based on the snippets above what you are exactly trying to achieve or the goal of having it update

Could you give us more context ?

Otherwise a quick answer is you could use the setter of Input instead of ngOnChanges to setup the obj value.

The only issue with you current flow is that by changing Obj -> you would trigger change to also change Obj1 when it was fine.

If you do need to sync state a lot, between two component with a parent / child, you could just create a service that hold the state for that, and each component reading or updating there

Comment: thank you Eren. This helps, so a service which will hold an observable and both these components subscribe to that. Is this what you are recommending?

Comment: It depends on the relation of component 1 & 2, but yeah a service that would hold that object and shared between the 2 components seems to be the easiest. I think the only thing that I am unsure is the change detection 

With the service or you current implementation you could end up retriggering the CD (change detection) for the component where actually nothing changed

Could you clarify the relation of Component 1 & Component 2 ?

Comment: When you pass an "Object" in an Input, you pass the "reference" of the object, so any change in the object (in any component -parent or children-) is showed. You only need use an Output to say that the object has changed -but it's unnecesary pass the object because is the same-

Comment: Component 1 is a search component in which search filters are dynamically built and sent to Component 2(Table component which displays the data from http). Component 2 applies the filters that it gets from Comp1 and passes to HTTP to get data. However, in Comp2, user will have an option to delete filters. I have added a screenshot if that will help

Comment: Eliseo, yes, that is what i am doing currently like updating the input with output.. which i felt is not the right way to do

Comment: I agree with Eliseo, but as he mentioned passing by "reference" could cause some change detection issues, since angular won't detect that the Input() changed ( the reference being the same, especially if you optimised with a changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush ) 

You could leave it as it is, if it's working for you.

It's my personal opinion here, but a service state for that could be handy as well in case you have more components. Or you wrapping it inside a parent component with a bit of restructure. Giving you a little example ( but it might help you with perf later on )

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the comments above, this is a way you could potentially organise your 2 components, this even removes the need to passing some of the filters or need for that

[image: Structure with a Parent component]

Basically in the above, your component 1 & component 2 are "dumb component" they just display UI based on @Input() and throw events on @Output()

Your component 3 is doing all the heavy lifting here and handling the data, this should get rid of the need to pass on some of the data between comp 1 & 2, and solve some of the CD concern I've expressed earlier

---- Edit ---

@Sam K

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { PuppiesModule } from './puppies.module';
import { Puppy } from './puppy.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: PuppiesModule })
export class PuppiesStoreService {
  // Make _puppiesSource private so it's not accessible from the outside, 
  // expose it as puppies$ observable (read-only) instead.
  // Write to _puppiesSource only through specified store methods below.
  private readonly _puppiesSource = new BehaviorSubject<Puppy[]>([]);

  // Exposed observable (read-only).
  readonly puppies$ = this._puppiesSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  // Get last value without subscribing to the puppies$ observable (synchronously).
  getPuppies(): Puppy[] {
    return this._puppiesSource.getValue();
  }

  private _setPuppies(puppies: Puppy[]): void {
    this._puppiesSource.next(puppies);
  }

  addPuppy(puppy: Puppy): void {
    const puppies = [...this.getPuppies(), puppy];
    this._setPuppies(puppies);
  }

  removePuppy(puppy: Puppy): void {
    const puppies = this.getPuppies().filter(p => p.id !== puppy.id);
    this._setPuppies(puppies);
  }

  adoptPuppy(puppy: Puppy): void {
    const puppies = this.getPuppies().map(p =>
      p.id === puppy.id ? new Puppy({ ...p, ...{ adopted: true } }) : p
    );
    this._setPuppies(puppies);
  }
}
```

This would be a nice example where the service is handling the state but also making the api call.

You could tweak around to :

- Not make it provided in 'root' but in the module that contains both your component 1 & component 2 ( if they are in the same module, otherwise leave it as `providedIn: 'root'`
- You could just hold and modify the object, if you don't want to do the http call for your results.

Here is another ressource that you might want to look https://dev.to/avatsaev/simple-state-management-in-angular-with-only-services-and-rxjs-41p8

Comment: can you please direct me to code examples on how to define the objects in a service and how to consume them in both Comp1 and Comp2